# javascript wildcard replace function

Tags: javascript, replace, wildcard

The below script results in :  res = NEW
I would like the result to be: res = NEW_okok_NEW

The .+ finds the first START and the last END, but I want it to find the next START and the next/following END, and replace it. How is that possible ?

```
<script>
$ (function () {
var str = "START_sometext_END_okok_START_someothertext_END"; 
var res = str.replace(/(START.+END)/g,'NEW');
alert(res);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the *greediness* out of your regexp.

```
str.replace(/START.+?(END)/g,'NEW');

=> "NEW_okok_NEW"
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/4Uj47/)

Answer (score 1):

You should make your regex ungreedy, so it matches the less it can instead of the most.

```
/(START.+END)/g
```

becomes

```
/(START.+?END)/g
```

Now, it stops to the closest END.
You can have more explanations about 'greedyness' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)